# Home Page Problem Html Code Images and Content home Page is html only

Tags: magento2.3

Home Page Problem Html Code Images and Content home Page is html only

[image]

Comment: Specify the problem into more details?

Comment: hi @DhirenVasoya thank you for replay my problem is After installing my template and activating it, the home page appears to me, as in the image above that I uploaded. This problem happened to me more than once with other templates and I solved it, but I do not remember how I solved it at that time

Comment: Hi @Nino, are you still getting the same issue or it has been fixed?

Comment: Hi @Magedivine Thank you for replay man i have fixed this issue

Comment: Can you please share the solution with the community? It will be helpful to others.

Comment: yes @magedivine the fixed you will copy code html from blocks in content to this site https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer paste code and copy code from output and done

Comment: That means your HTML were missing some tags. There was no Magento related issue.

Comment: There is no problem doing this in Magento magento not like any platform like prestashop or opencart Magento is not a graphics platform any problem within Magento of this type can be fixed from within back end But software problems do not do the same thing as the problem that happened to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue Html is fixed go to Content blocks and check your home page you chose and copy code html to this site [Html Filter](https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer)

and paste code and copy new code from output and done